# UITabBar and tableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uitabbar

I need to add a UITabBar without UITabBarController in my tableViewController.

when I add tabBar on my storyboard my problem is tabBar is showed down the NavigationBar or, if are present any tableview's cells, down the tableViewCell. How can I put my tabBar in the bottom side of my tableViewController???

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you....
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2099944?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

// Disable this

```
UITabBarController.tabbar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

// Enable this

```
UITabBarController.tabbar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: I have not a UITabBarController.... I created in my storyboard, inside my tableViewController, a UITabBar object! this object is viewed down my tableView. How can I put this bar bottom to the screen?